# Spring: JSON to Java Object using @RequestBody

Tags: jquery, json, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

I'am working with spring Rest Web service.I'am not able to convert `JSON` to Java `Object` using `@RequestBody`.

Controller Method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String test(@RequestBody Student s)
{

    System.out.print(s.getName()+s.getMark()+s.getRollNo());

    return "ok";
}
```

POJO class:

```
 public class Student implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int mark;
private String name;
private int rollNo;
    // getters and setters
  }
```

MessageConverter in Serlvet-context.xml:

```
    <beans:bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></beans:bean>
 <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
<beans:property name="messageConverters">
  <beans:list>
    <beans:ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
  </beans:list>
</beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

I am using `POSTMAN` rest client chrome plugin for calling the webservice. `JSON object` passed is:

```
{"mark":30,"name":"sam","rollNo":100}
```

I am getting '`415 Unsupported Media Type`' as response when calling the web service.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like your JSON string is wrong. See the quotes

Comment: sorry.By mistake I have written here like that.I have edited it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in the way you are invoking the Controller for the POSTMAN client.

It's missing the `Content-Type: application/json` HTTP Header

Answer (score 0):

Just Do This

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test",method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```